# Coinductive principle for streams

Tags: coq, proof, coinduction

I am trying to prove the following principle for stream predicates (defined in the standard library).

```
From Coq Require Import Streams.

Lemma mystream_ind :
  forall A (P : Stream A -> Prop),
    (forall s, ForAll P (tl s) -> ForAll P s) ->
    forall s, ForAll P s.
Proof.
  intros A P H.
  cofix Cof.
  destruct s as [a s].
  constructor; auto.
  destruct (H (Cons a s) (Cof s)); auto.
  Fail Guarded.
Abort.
```

From my understanding of the syntactical guard conditions imposed by `cofix`, I will never be able to complete the proof this way because in the proof term, `Cof s` must appear under `H`, which is not a constructor nor a match, etc.

Is there another way to do it in Coq? I defined `ForAll` as an explicit fixpoint with [paco](http://plv.mpi-sws.org/paco/) and tried to prove the principle, without success (I couldn't instantiate `H` at all).

EDIT: this lemma is not provable as `False` can be derived from it by taking `P := fun s => False` (thank you Maëlan).

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I believe this statement not to be provable. With `P := fun s => False` the constantly false proposition, we have that `Forall P s` is false for every stream `s`, so the premise of your statement is true (because it is an implication whose left-hand side is false) but the conclusion is false.

Comment: I indeed managed to prove `False` assuming `mystream_ind`... Thanks!